# How to Filter out a String pod/ from Kubectl Output

Tags: linux, bash, parsing, kubernetes

So I am trying to write a for loop to gather all of the described information from the following command across all pods within all namespaces.

```
kubectl describe pod <pod_name>
```

I am using the following command to generate output within the system:

```
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o Name
```

This provides output similar to the following:

```
pod/compose-78f95d4f8c-zppf2
pod/compose-api-6ffb89dc58-5rk84
pod/coredns-5644d7b6d9-4qh7k
pod/coredns-5644d7b6d9-s946h
pod/etcd-docker-desktop
pod/kube-apiserver-docker-desktop
pod/kube-controller-manager-docker-desktop
pod/kube-proxy-trdx5
pod/kube-scheduler-docker-desktop
pod/metrics-server-d58c94f4d-bvdbv
pod/storage-provisioner
pod/vpnkit-controller
pod/dashboard-metrics-scraper-c79c65bb7-s26tz
pod/kubernetes-dashboard-56484d4c5-xg7v6
```

My ultimate goal would be to use the following to gather all of the described pods for a text file later:

```
for i in $(kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o Name); do kubectl describe pods $i; done >> cluster_description.txt
```

However, the `pod/` portion causes an error and I am not able to see anything in the output as it is just empty bytes.

QUESTION:
How can I strip off the `pod/` portion from the following command so I can get the output I want?

```
(kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o Name
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kubectl describe pod -A > cluster_description.txt
```

`-A` --all-namespaces

Comment: this also worked for me, but I want to get more granular with how I want to name files and what not later on. Thanks though, it definitely describes all pods.

Answer (score 4):

There is cut to splitting by '/' and getting second column `cut -d'/' -f2`.

```
$(kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o Name | cut -d'/' -f2)
```

Comment: So this does strip out the portion but if I use it within the for loop it returns as no valid pods. The reason for this is the default pods that make up the core components of the Kubernetes Workspace with Docker Overlay appear as pods even though they will not register as pods. Though the cut does work. I think the --all-namespaces just should be taken off and I really shouldn't specify the namespaces.